# Style question !condition agains condition == NULL

Tags: c, coding-style

If you call some function, and that functions returns NULL in case of an error (think of `malloc()` or `fopen()` for example), which of the two is better:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[0], "r");

if (fp == NULL) {
    // handle error
}
```

or

```
if (!fp) {
    // handle error
}
```

Is it just a matter of style? I think the first one is clearer being more explicit but then I rarely code in C :-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prefer comparing with NULL, because it makes it clear that both operands of the comparison are supposed to be pointers. This

(!p)

or this

(p == 0)

require that you know what p's type is (an integer? a boolean?) at a glance. I am of the opinion that all coding should be done with the assumption that you are going to have to debug the thing at 4am (that's 4 in the morning, for the sleepless out there) 9 months later. In that case every little bit helps.

Oh, and it's good practice to place constants as the first operand when testing for equality, so that the compiler will abort with an error if you accidentally turn it into an assignment.

Comment: Here is what I never got about the whole place-the-constant-on-the-LHS thing: if I can remember to do that, can't I remember to put two `=` symbols?

Comment: Most compilers warn about having an assignment in a condition, so that's not a big issue, but still helpful sometimes.

Comment: @Jason: The first is a practice that's automatically followed, the second requires that you actually take care to press the = twice and that the editor will actually catch the key-press. Remember, at 4am!

Comment: @Kos: True, unless you are modifying 3rd-party code by people who do not care about reducing compiler warnings. In that case a warning that's related to your modifications could easily get lost in the noise.

Comment: I don't like the reversed conditions: I'm not comparing null with something; I'm testing whether something is null.  It reads wrong - Yoda-like, per @dennycrane.  Plus, it breaks down when you are comparing two variables...so it is a poor crutch.

Comment: @thkala: I'm with Jonathan Leffler on this one.

Comment: Well, to some degree it is a matter of style. In any case, such idioms become second nature after a while, although I admit they can be counter-intuitive to those who don't use them.

Answer (score 7):

I believe this is a matter of style. Personally, I like the second option better. Others like the first one because it is clearer and more "proper". Some people even write `if (NULL == fp)` so they can never accidentally forget one `=` and turn it into an assignment. All in all though, I think it's a matter of taste, and it's probably more important to be somewhat consistent.

Comment: I don't like Yoda conditions. It feels like saying "If green is the water, ...". Also, my compilers kick me in the nuts for assigning in a conditional anyway.

Comment: In some cases, like this one: `if (SOME_CONST == long_function_name(lots, of, parameters, with, long, names)){` by putting constant in the front you don't have to scroll to see what are you comparing to. (I hate to use newlines for function parameters, so I preffer this approach).

Comment: I love "Yoda conditions" - finally a phrase for this silliness :) Thanks denny!

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the first one in this case, as you are explicitly comparing the value to see if it's null (which happens to be 0).

The second one reads as if `fp` is a boolean, which it isn't.

It's like saying "Is this pointer invalid?" vs "Is this pointer false?"

Which one is more readable to *you* is, of course, a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer "=="; I think the reader has to think less.  This is also why I detest typedefs.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it just a matter of style?

In the case of C, it is just a matter of style as both are correct, but in general, I believe more people (including me) prefer an explicit comparison (`ptr == NULL`) as evidenced by the following:

- C++0x introduces a `nullptr` keyword to emphasize that it is more than just a mere number or boolean value.
- Java forces explicit comparisons (`obj == null`) and does not allow `!obj`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is matter of style. `fp == NULL` *(oops, I wrote `fp = NULL`...)* is very clear and explicit in that it express, and it is good for those not familiar with all C's twists and turns. Altough `!fp` is very like an idiom and pun: "there's **not**(!)hing at fp". Ant it is short. For this i like `!fp`. I think C designers also like this otherwise they should not define `!` for pointers. :)

Comment: @thkala: Yes. (And that's my reason to dislike that `==`:))